# Dynamically add hook to process switching in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, hook, scheduler

In the kernel, how can one hook the process scheduler to add hook every process switch, with a loadable kernel module?

I want to determine and analyze every event of process/thread switching in the OS.

Comment: http://criticalblue.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/linux_scheduler_notes_final.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze, it already exists: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Events

You can refer the code that is invoked by the perf tool for monitoring the context-switch events if you are interested in the implementation.